# How to conditionally enable or disable Kendo UI buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I have this dictionary in a controller function:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> Editable = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
switch (Mode)
{
    case VIEW_MODE.VIEW:

        Editable.Add("FirstName", true);
        Editable.Add("MiddleName", true);
        Editable.Add("LastName", true);
        Editable.Add("DateOfBirth", true);
        Editable.Add("Age", true);
        Editable.Add("Height", true);
        Editable.Add("CityName", true);
        Editable.Add("MemberType", true);
        Editable.Add("MemberRoleList", true);
        Editable.Add("Mobile", true);
        Editable.Add("Email", true);
        Editable.Add("PIN", true);
        Editable.Add("Phone", true);
        Editable.Add("Btnsave", true);
        Editable.Add("BtnsaveAjax", true);
        Editable.Add("BtnEditAjax", false);
        break;
    case VIEW_MODE.ADD:

        Editable.Add("FirstName", false);
        Editable.Add("MiddleName", false);
        Editable.Add("LastName", false);
        Editable.Add("DateOfBirth", false);
        Editable.Add("Age", false);
        Editable.Add("Height", false);
        Editable.Add("CityName", false);
        Editable.Add("MemberType", false);
        Editable.Add("MemberRoleList", false);
        Editable.Add("Mobile", false);
        Editable.Add("Email", false);
        Editable.Add("PIN", false);
        Editable.Add("Phone", false);
        Editable.Add("Remark", false);
        Editable.Add("Btnsave", false);
        Editable.Add("BtnsaveAjax", false);
        Editable.Add("BtnEditAjax", true);

        break;
    case VIEW_MODE.EDIT:

        Editable.Add("FirstName", false);
        Editable.Add("MiddleName", false);
        Editable.Add("LastName", false);
        Editable.Add("DateOfBirth", false);
        Editable.Add("Age", false);
        Editable.Add("Height", false);
        Editable.Add("CityName", false);
        Editable.Add("MemberType", false);
        Editable.Add("MemberRoleList", false);
        Editable.Add("Mobile", false);
        Editable.Add("Email", false);
        Editable.Add("PIN", false);
        Editable.Add("Phone", false);
        Editable.Add("Remark", false);                  
        Editable.Add("Btnsave", false);
        Editable.Add("BtnsaveAjax", false);
        Editable.Add("BtnEditAjax", true);
}
```

Depending on this dictionary, I need to enable or disable one of my form button in the view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("BtnsaveAjax")
    .Content("Save - AJAX")
    .Enable(true)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "float:right", type = "button" })
    .Events(ev => ev.Click("saveDetails"))
)
```

I need to enable or disable this button using an if condition, which will check if my editable `btnsaveAjax` is true or false.

Comment: The official documentation could be worth a look. Specificially the "enabled"-part.  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/button

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix some punctuation mistakes. I also indented the body properly: 4 spaces are for indenting code samples - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can check that in the controller and pass it via `ViewBag`, for example, something like:

```
if (Editable["BtnsaveAjax"] == true)
    ViewBag.btnIsEnabled = true;
else
    ViewBag.btnIsEnabled = false;
```

And in your button something like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("BtnsaveAjax")
    .Content("Save - AJAX")
    .Enable((bool)ViewBag.btnIsEnabled)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "float:right", type = "button" })
    .Events(ev => ev.Click("saveDetails"))
)
```